# Copy version of file from other branch or commit without overwriting current version?

Tags: git

As part of a test script, I want to copy the version of a file from the head of `origin/master` ***without*** overwriting the current version of that file in the branch I have currently checked out.

To explain, if I run:

```
git checkout origin/master -- a.txt
```

This will overwrite `a.txt` in the branch I am currently in. **I don't want this.**

I want to copy `a.txt` from `origin/master` and save it as a new file with a provided filepath, e.g. `/tmp/a.master.txt`

I know I can `git checkout origin/master`, do the copying manually, then checkout my other branch. But is there some git magic I can use instead? Ideally I want to be able to use the current state of `a.txt` which may or may not be committed, and using `git stash` seems too risky.

Comment: Note that there are some caveats with *either* of `git cat-file -p <rev>:<path>` or `git show <rev>:<path>`. In particular, both *smudge filters* and end-of-line conversion (LF to CRLF) happen during `git checkout`. Since you're not using `git checkout`, these filters *may* be skipped. Modern Git has grown the ability to run the filters on non-checkout extractions, but they're optional here. The default for `git cat-file -p` is to omit them unless explicitly called-for. It's not clear what the default is for `git show` (which mentions `--textconv` but describes how it affects *diff* only!).

Comment: @torek What about `git cat-file blob`, though?

Comment: Since `git cat-file` is plumbing, it should never change behavior in an incompatible way. The old version never did text conversions or filters, with `-p` or with `blob`, so the new version that now has `--textconv` and `--filters` must not filter/convert unless you use the new flags. But `git show` is a *porcelain* command, not a plumbing command, so it may change behavior any time, if the new behavior is better for the average human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git cat-file blob` to get a specific version of a file. For example, you can run `git cat-file blob origin/master:a.txt >/tmp/a.master.txt` to check out the version of `a.txt` at the revision `origin/master`.

You can also specify other, arbitrarily complex revision expressions for this as well, provided that they point to a blob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git show` to help do this:

```
git show origin/master:a.txt > saved-a.txt
```

In place of `origin/master`, you could use any branch name, tag, commit number, etc.